Is there a simple way in Thunderbird to open an html-Email in a browser?
Is there a button, keyboard shortcut, add-on, ... anything?
If it were, I could use the uBlock Origin and other add-ons in my browser to keep things the way I want, instead of trying to achieve the same things in the thunderbird app.
